# NMaximize not always returning solution

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization, precision-and-accuracy

This question is related to a previous question and answer here:

[NMinimize or NMaximize for a dynamic problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197537/nminimize-or-nmaximize-for-a-dynamic-problem)

but tackles a different problem.

I am trying to solve a simple linear quadratic optimal depletion problem.
 Choose $q(t)$ from $t=0$ to $ T$ so as to maximize the objective when $R(t+1)=R(t)-q(t).$
 My code is here:

```
 T = 100; p = 1.; δ = 0.05127; ρ = 1./(1. + δ); c = 50.; R0 = 1.;
obj[qlist_ /; VectorQ[qlist, NumericQ]] :=
 Module[{Rlist, obj},
  Rlist = FoldList[(#1 - #2) &, R0, qlist];

If[Min[Rlist] < 0, Return[-1000]]; (* Constraint to keep R(t)>=0 for all t *)

(* This is the objective function *)
Sum[ρ^t*(p*qlist[[t + 1]] - 
      0.5 c ((qlist[[t + 1]])^2)/Rlist[[t + 1]]), {t, 0, T - 1}]
  ]

choicevar = Table[Unique[q], {i, 0, T - 1}];
sol = NMaximize[Prepend[Thread[0 <= choicevar], obj[choicevar]], 
   choicevar];
sol[[1]]
```

I have an analytical solution to this class of problems and this code works perfectly when $R0=100$.
 But for $R0=1$ as above, it fails.
 The problem also wont solve if I set $T=250$ and $R0=100$.
 
The failures are of two kinds. 
1) failures to converge to desired accuracy, or 
2) violation of the constraint $(R(t)=>0)$, Returning a solution -1000. 

The problems that will not solve all seem to have solutions (in the later periods) where q gets close to zero (the real solution may be or order 10^-3, for instance) so I suspect the issue has to do with accuracy or precision but I tried variations and allowing up to 10000 iterations and it does not work.

Can anyone please help me unlock the power of NMaximize? 
At this point, Excel Solver seems to be a better solution but I refuse to believe that! Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the step size for candidate solution in the NMaximize too large? you may want  to use another solver (AMPL, GAMS,or Excel,of course) that you have.

Comment: A the moment, I have reasons for wanting a Mathematica based solution. I have a hard time believing that Mathematica cannot at least be on par with Excel Solver. I don't expect it to be as good as GAMS, but that's beside the point. If Mathematica can perform, it is best for me to make it work.

Comment: ok,hope someone post the good answer :) by the way,the solution itself exists. try ``
  obj[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 0.010}], T]]`` this returns positive value.

Comment: As I posted, I have an analytical solution to this particular problem. Call it a benchmark if you will.

Comment: Are you asking for "generic solver for optimal control problem" ?

Comment: @Xminer Yes, more or less. But general only in the sense that it only really needs to perform well for problems that have good mathematical properties (e.g. strictly concave). Like I said, The problem above is in some ways the easiest problem that a nonlinear optimizer should be able to handle so if excel can do it, I am sure Mathematica can do it. Is it a Method->"" issue? is it options under the methods? is accuracy or precision? That is where my head is at. Mathematical has to be able to handle it  but I can't seem to be able to get it to.

Comment: I don't think the constraint in the code `Thread[0 <= choicevar]` is equivalent to `Rt => 0`.  Consequently, many inputs are permitted that yield `obj[] == -1000`.  If a numerical solver sees a lot of such results, it will decide it has found the maximum.

Comment: @Dr777 I found that this is not the problem of mathematica,check my updated answer :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 The constraint in choicevar is not on Rt, it is on the choice variables y.

Comment: (1) There are no variables y in the question. (2) You enforce a constraint `Min[Rlist] < 0` with a penalty, which I took to be "the constraint (Rt=>0)" mentioned in the question; however, there is no such constraint "Rt=>0" mentioned elsewhere, esp. just what the definition of "Rt" is.  Perhaps you meant R(t) >= 0, but again there is no definition of R(t), although it is mentioned earlier. -- In short, the question needs clarification. I know how to answer the question I thought you were asking, but it's unclear to me what you are actually asking.

Comment: @MichaelE2 (1) $y$ is the mistake of $q(t)$ ,(2) $R(t)$ is the state variable following the dynamics $R(t+1)=R(t)-q(t)$,I think

Comment: Yes, sorry. My mistake to have replied using y instead of q for this problem.

Answer (score 4):

**Updated**)

In general,we need to carefully set ***the feasible region of control.***

I mean,

> sol = NMaximize[Prepend[Thread[0 <= choicevar **<= 0.020**],
>   obj[choicevar]],choicevar];

so just check the result.

```
T = 100; p = 1.; \[Delta] = 0.05127; \[Rho] = 
 1./(1. + \[Delta]); c = 50.; R0 = 1.;
obj[qlist_ /; VectorQ[qlist, NumericQ]] := 
 Module[{Rlist, obj}, Rlist = FoldList[(#1 - #2) &, R0, qlist];
  If[Min[Rlist] < 0, 
   Return[-1000]];(*Constraint to keep R\[GreaterEqual]0*)(*This is \
the objective function*)
  Sum[\[Rho]^
     t*(p*qlist[[t + 1]] - 
      0.5 c ((qlist[[t + 1]])^2)/Rlist[[t + 1]]), {t, 0, T - 1}]]

choicevar = Table[Unique[q], {i, 0, T - 1}];
sol = NMaximize[
   Prepend[Thread[0 <= choicevar <= 0.02], obj[choicevar]], choicevar];
sol[[1]]
```

=>

> 0.150353

```
ListLinePlot@Values@Last@sol
```

[image]

If you can not solve the problem, please try to make sure that the conditions you imposed.
Even if not in the text, you often need additional one.

---

Perhaps I think the function approximation using the pseudospectral method is the most efficient, but I have never done it...

so,I used heuristics.

First,Let's sampling and guess the optimal solution.

```
Table[try = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 0.014}], {T, 10}];
  data = {try[[All, #]], obj[try[[All, #]]]} & /@ Range[1, 10];
  SortBy[data, -#[[2]] &][[1]], {1000}];
Mean@sample[[All, 1]] // ListLinePlot
```

[image]

It seems that we can approximate it with $a*Exp(-ax)$

Define it and maximize the obj for its parameter $a$

```
f[x_, a_] := a*Exp[-a*x];

run[a_] := Block[{candsol}, candsol = Table[f[i, a], {i, 100}];
  obj[candsol]];

Table[{i, run[i]}, {i, 0, 1, 0.01}] // SortBy[#, -#[[2]] &] & // First
```

> {0.02, 0.148254}

```
Plot[f[x, 0.02], {x, 0, 100}];
```

[image]

May it help you solve your problem.

Comment: This is nice analysis @Xminer, but my problem is not specifically the solution to the depletion problem above. I already know that solution. It is really about trying to setup a quick mathematica applet that might allow for relatively reliable solutions for this class of problems. The corresponding Hamiltonians are almost always strictly concave in the state and control and typically can be shown to have a unique interior solution. So they are very regular problems that I would think Mathematica would handle without much of a fuss!

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Will need to investigate how long this will work before I bug down again. As I always maintained. It would surprise me if mma really could not handle problems that excel solver routinely works with.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I think the problem boils down to:

```
obj2[qlist_ /; VectorQ[qlist, NumericQ]] := Module[{Rlist, obj},
   Rlist = FoldList[(#1 - #2) &, R0, qlist];
   (*This is the objective function*)
   ρ^Range[0, Length@qlist - 1].(p*qlist - 
      0.5 c*qlist^2/Most@Rlist)];
grad[qlist_ /; VectorQ[qlist, NumericQ]] := Module[{Rlist, obj, dQ},
   Rlist = FoldList[(#1 - #2) &, R0, qlist];
   dQ = IdentityMatrix[Length@qlist];
   (*This is the jacobian function*)
   ρ^Range[0, Length@qlist - 1].(p*dQ - 
      c*DiagonalMatrix@qlist/Most@Rlist + 
      0.5 c*qlist^2 LowerTriangularize[
         ConstantArray[-1, {Length@qlist, Length@qlist}], -1]/
        Most[Rlist]^2)];

sol = FindMaximum[{obj2[choicevar], 
     And @@ Append[Thread[0 <= choicevar], Total@choicevar <= 1]}, 
    Transpose@{choicevar, 
      RandomVariate[DirichletDistribution[ConstantArray[1, T + 1]]]}, 
    Gradient -> grad[choicevar]]; // AbsoluteTiming
sol[[1]]
(*
  {0.719767, Null}
  0.150353
*)
```

I computed & coded the gradient `grad[]` by hand, because it was easier to derive an efficient numerical code that way.

`FindMaximum` on the OP's functions took over a minute.  `NMaximize` was much slower, naturally, but since the OP mentions that the function is "strictly concave", `FindMaximum` seems the better tool.  If you want to try `NMaximize`, then the `DirichletDistribution` is a convenient way to get initial points for this particular domain (`NMaximize` has trouble finding them automatically):

```
Method -> {Automatic, (* or whatever *)
  "InitialPoints" -> 
    RandomVariate[DirichletDistribution[ConstantArray[1, T + 1]], 10], 
  "SearchPoints" -> 10}
```

Comment: Good ideas @Michael E2. I am trying to make this flexible so I went for setting random initial points rather than the gradient. The DirichletDistribution functions better but I substituted it for a uniform distribution for  a more general set up for other problems. With a scaling factor, it works better than a hard constraint on choicevariables. Also, Total@choicevar<=1 is slower than Min[Rlist<...] in obj[]. NMinimize on original problem, with Uniform solves in under 30s. Much slower than with gradient, but much less time than coding the gradient! FindMin is not as fast with this setup.